Livewire update API calls on seconds elapsed of a song
Hello to everyone!
I created using Livewire (PHP LARAVEL) components an API call that returns me a specific song. The return is excatly:
['song' =>[
'title'=>'....',
'artist'=>'....'.
'art'=>'....',
'seconds_elapsed'=> '....',
'seconds_total'=>'....',
]]

Everything works, I did a logic where the parent div does a "wire:poll.{{$remainingTime}}s="fetchSongData"" (remainingTime is a difference between seconds_total and seconds_elapsed to have the remainingTime of the song)
So everytime a song finishes, he's going to "refresh" the component and change all the actual properties.
The thing is... I want to actually see in LIVE the seconds_elapsed changing because in the API, they change every seconds but since I call the API once in a "remainingTime" average of 3 minutes, the seconds are going to update only when I refresh the page.
I tried to use wire:poll.750ms, and I can see on my terminal that he's displaying new lines of:
"2024-04-12 16:27:10 ..................................................................... ~ -4s"

Every seconds, but the seconds elapsed remain static.
I did a javascript to get the seconds_elapsed once, and start counting by that seconds he gets. When I refresh the value is stored so it's going to count from that value that I had before refreshing.
Though this "solution" seems to work, the counting doesn't match perfectly the timing of the seconds_elapsed that came with API. So everytime I refresh the page, the seconds are going a little backwards or even forward.
There's a way to see in LIVE seconds with some Livewire properties, method or I don't know? Or I need to use Javascript? Still with Javascript it doesn't work well, and it corrupts with the "wire:navigate" script of Livewire of my nav items.
This is the actual code:
class TitleSong extends Component
{

    public $songTitle;
    public $songArtist;
    public $songImage;
    public $secondsTotal;
    public $secondsElapsed;
    public $elementToShow;
    public $remainingTime;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.title-song');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->fetchSongData();
    }

    public function fetchSongData()
    {
        try{
        $response = Http::get('myAPI');
        $data = $response->json();

        $this->songArtist = $data['song']['artist'];
        $this->secondsElapsed = $data['song']['seconds_elapsed'];
        $this->secondsTotal = $data['song']['seconds_total'];
        $this->songImage = $data['song']['art'];
        $this->songTitle = $data['song']['title'];

        $remainingTime = $this->secondsTotal - $this->secondsElapsed;
        $this->remainingTime = $remainingTime;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        dd($th->getMessage());
    }
    }

}

My component blade.php:
<div wire:poll.{{$remainingTime}}s="fetchSongData">
    @if ($elementToShow === 'songTitle')
        <h1 id="songTitle" style="color: var(--quaternary-color); font-weight: 600" class="text-4xl">{{$songTitle}}</h1>
    @elseif ($elementToShow === 'songArtist')
        <p id="songArtist" class="mt-2 ml-1" style="color: var(--quinary-color); font-weight: 400; font-size: 15px">{{$songArtist}}</p>
    @elseif ($elementToShow === 'secondsElapsed')
        <span id="secondsElapsed" class="current-time">{{$secondsElapsed}}</span>
    @elseif ($elementToShow === 'secondsTotal')
        <span id="secondsTotal" class="total-time"> {{substr($secondsTotal, 0, 1) . ':' . substr($secondsTotal, 1, 2)}}</span>
    @elseif($elementToShow === 'songImage')
    <img style="position: absolute; left: 12%; top: 2%; border-radius:20px; z-index: 1" width="220px" height="200px" src="{{$songImage}}" /> alt="">
    @endif
</div>

I deleted the JS since it was not perfect and needed some adjustement.
Thanks if you read all and if you could help I would apprecciate that!
I've tried to use wire:poll.750ms on the HTML element of "secondsElapsed", I tried to use Javascript Vanilla to count++ the value of SecondsElapsed (but seems to bug when added wire:navigate to the nav-link even there's no relation between this tag and the nav-link. I tried to ask even to Livewire dev, but they keep giving me short answers to how I should make my code more "efficient" or to use Alpine even though I don't know alpine.
Still using wire:poll.750ms I expected an output to be refreshed every ms, but it's not working as the:
<div wire:poll.{{$remainingTime}}s="fetchSongData">

that is infact working. I even tried to request another time the same API but getting only the secondsElapsed and then doing a
<div wire:poll.750ms="fetchSecondsElapsed">

but with no luck...

// I can't explain in details but below is an optimize code you can adopt.

class TitleSong extends Component
{
    public $songTitle;
    public $songArtist;
    public $songImage;
    public $secondsTotal;
    public $secondsElapsed;
    public $elementToShow;
    public $remainingTime;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.title-song');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->fetchSongData();
    }

    public function fetchSongData()
    {
        try {
            $response = Http::get('myAPI');
            $data = $response->json();

            $this->songArtist = $data['song']['artist'];
            $this->secondsElapsed = $data['song']['seconds_elapsed'];
            $this->secondsTotal = $data['song']['seconds_total'];
            $this->songImage = $data['song']['art'];
            $this->songTitle = $data['song']['title'];

            $remainingTime = $this->secondsTotal - $this->secondsElapsed;
            $this->remainingTime = $remainingTime;
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            dd($th->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public function updatedSecondsElapsed($value)
    {
        // Handle logic if needed when seconds elapsed is updated
    }
}


// Modify your livewire code
<div wire:poll.{{$remainingTime}}s="fetchSongData">
    <!-- Your existing Blade code -->

    <script>
        setInterval(function () {
            @this.call('fetchSongData'); // Call the Livewire fetchSongData method
        }, 1000); // Update every second
    </script>
</div>

